# what is the best way the save fpdf into database?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm new in PHP and  i want to saving pdf into database
I would like to know what the best way to save fpdf into database?
I'm using BLOB type just to save the content of pdf but i want to get the file pdf to read into table and see the content when i clicked to the file.

My code to get the content is:

```
$query = "select nomeUser,email,nomeVoucher,categoria,preco,confirmacao,filePDF
from historico
LIMIT $start, $per_page";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        if($confirmacao == "a confirmar"){
        echo("<tbody >");           
        echo("<tr><td>$nomeUser</td>");
        echo "<td>$email</td>";
        echo("<td >$nomeVoucher</td>");
        echo("<td >$categoria</td>");
        echo("<td>$preco €</td>");
        echo("<td>$confirmacao</td>");
```

filePDF is the name where i save the content of my fpdf
How can i do this?

Comment: Standard answer: don't save files in the database. There's very very few usage cases that justify it, and many many reasons for why it's painful

Comment: Why would you want to save it in database? Save the data in database and retrieve it in your pdf when ever required

Comment: How i retrieve it into pdf file?

Comment: Further to Marc's comment, For all the enterprise systems I've worked on, the only thing stored in the database is the filename/path. The file is created, saved and then it's path inserted into the db. In one system, we dealt with about 150 a4 tiffs per day, for the duration of an academic year. Simple, quick and deadly easy to view or edit the images with any software package, without messy retrieval and updating of an image in a database. If you need to look at a fist-full of images that were actually in the database, you'd have to extract them to disk anyway.

Comment: Well I need to save my content into Database because I need send it to email when the user click.